# Replace lines in a protobuf file using python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I have an existing proto file that I would like to change. What I would like to do is read the file in, change a value or two, and then write it back out to disk as a .proto file, to be read by another program. According to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/index), I should be able to write something like this:

```
from google.protobuf import message

msg = message.Message()
msg.ParseFromString(infile.read())

... (make changes)

outfile.write(msg.SerializeToString())
```

But it just gives me a `NotImplementedError`. Where is the library I need to interface with protobuf text files? [This](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.text_format) seems to work for C++, why hasn't it been implemented for python? (No, the functions in google.protobuf.text_format aren't implemented either).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be confusing several different concepts here.

`message.Message` is an abstract base class. You need to construct an instance of the specific derived class you're interested in.

`.proto` files contain type definitions, not message data. You must compile your `.proto` file using `protoc`, the Protocol Compiler. It will generate Python code which you can then import into your program in order to construct the specific type you want. Please see the [Protobuf tutorial](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial) for details.

Use `ParseFromString()` to parse *binary* protobuf data from a file, and use `SerializeToString()` to convert the message back into *binary* data. You should almost always use binary format for protobuf data.

The `TextFormat` class you reference implements an alternative encoding of protobufs that is human-readable. This format is *not* recommended for most use cases. If you want a human-readable format, you may be better off with JSON, but it will always be much slower and less-compact than binary encodings. `TextFormat` is occasionally useful for debugging (printing out a message) and sometimes for writing message data as source code. `TextFormat` is available in the Python library as the [`text_format` module](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/google.protobuf.text_format-module).

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. So, is there no library for generating the .proto definition files themselves?

Comment: Correct. `.proto` files are source code. If you want to generate protobuf types programmatically, look at the "descriptor" APIs, as constructing them will be much cleaner than generating text.